# Erro no dado recebido em PHP

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

Esse erro apareceu após a migração de hospedagem.

```
Warning: number_format() expects parameter 1 to be float, string given in /home/bramo472/public_html/evolucamp.com.br/doutor/_app/Helpers/Orcamento.class.php on line 105

Warning: number_format() expects parameter 1 to be float, string given in /home/bramo472/public_html/evolucamp.com.br/doutor/_app/Helpers/Orcamento.class.php on line 105

Warning: number_format() expects parameter 1 to be float, string given in /home/bramo472/public_html/evolucamp.com.br/doutor/_app/Helpers/Orcamento.class.php on line 105

Warning: number_format() expects parameter 1 to be float, string given in /home/bramo472/public_html/evolucamp.com.br/doutor/_app/Helpers/Orcamento.class.php on line 105

Warning: number_format() expects parameter 1 to be float, string given in /home/bramo472/public_html/evolucamp.com.br/doutor/_app/Helpers/Orcamento.class.php on line 105

Warning: number_format() expects parameter 1 to be float, string given in /home/bramo472/public_html/evolucamp.com.br/doutor/_app/Helpers/Orcamento.class.php on line 105
MENSAGEM
Erro ao cadastrar: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'como_conheceu' in 'field list
```

Banco de dados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Arquivo que é acusado o erro:

```
  //Monta a tabela com os itens do carrinho
  private function AmmountCart() {
    if (isset($_SESSION['CARRINHO']) && !empty($_SESSION['CARRINHO'])):
      $this->Data['orc_cart'] = null;

      foreach ($_SESSION['CARRINHO'] as $IDPRO => $PRODUCT):
        $produtos .= "<tr><td> Código: </td> <td> <strong> {$PRODUCT['prod_codigo']} </strong> </td></tr>";
        $produtos .= "<tr><td> Produto: </td> <td> <strong> {$PRODUCT['prod_title']} </strong> </td></tr>";
        $produtos .= "<tr><td> Valor unitário: </td> <td> <strong> R$ ". number_format($PRODUCT['prod_preco'], 2, ',', '.')." </strong> </td></tr>";
        $produtos .= "<tr><td> Modelos: </td> <td> <strong>Quantidades:</strong> </td></tr>";
        foreach ($PRODUCT['modelos'] as $itens => $quantidade):
          $produtos .= "<tr><td> {$itens} </td> <td> <strong> {$quantidade} </strong> </td></tr>";
        endforeach;
        $produtos .= "<tr style='background: #eee; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc; padding: 2px; height:2px;'><td ></td><td></td></tr>";
      endforeach;
      $produtos .= "<tr><td>Valor total </td><td>R$ {$this->Total}</td></tr>";

      $this->Data['orc_cart'] = $produtos;
    endif;
  }
```

Essa é alinha do erro:

```
$produtos .= "<tr><td> Valor unitário: </td> <td> <strong> R$ ". number_format($PRODUCT['prod_preco'], 2, ',', '.')." </strong> </td></tr>";
```

Comment: Você usou `number_format($PRODUCT['prod_preco'], 2, ',', '.')` e o erro diz: `number_format` espera um *float* como entrada, mas você passou uma *string*. Infere-se, então, que `$PRODUCT['prod_preco']` é uma *string* e você precisa converter para *float*.

Comment: De um `var_dump` na variável `$PRODUCT['prod_preco']`, algum caracter está vindo errado, pode até ser uma vírgula no lugar de ponto ou espaços em branco.

Comment: Dei um `var_dump` o resultado foi `NULL`.

Como poderia converter em float?

Comment: Será algo na hospedagem? usava locaweb e funcionava, agora migrei o cliente para hostgator e gera este erro

Comment: Tem mais cara de ser erro de lógica no seu código. Se está chegando `NULL` e não deveria ser nulo, você fez coisa errada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Não precisa ser FLOAT não**, `number_format` aceita perfeitamente string, veja:

```
echo number_format('2.0', 2);
```

Ou seja, desde que o formato seja "entendível" como numero pelo PHP, estará valendo.

O problema é que você tem linhas com valores nulos, e nulo não é um formato valido aqui, eu não sei porque esta com `null` pode ser porque esta usando `JOIN` na query e esta trazendo coisa que não devia, se não for o caso de `JOIN` então é porque de fato tem sim valores como `NULL`, então simplesmente é porque ninguém definiu o valor unitário do produto ainda e nem deveria ser exibido valor, ou exibir uma mensagem no lugar.

Mas pelo que vejo você esta usando SESSION para um carrinho de compras, o problema então provavelmente **é em outro lugar**, você deve ter um método chamado `AddCart` ou `AddProduct` (hipoteticos), na hora de adicionar a sessão você não deve estar enviando corretamente o valor do produto, aliais nem deve estar enviando nada, então `$PRODUCT['prod_preco']` **provavelmente não existe**, e o PHP converte para `NULL`

Fora que pelo erro:

> Erro ao cadastrar: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'como_conheceu' in 'field list

Tua query esta errada, claramente esta tentando fazer uma query com o nome de de uma coluna que não existe.

Answer (score -1):

É possível que esta nova hospedagem esteja com a versão do PHP 7 e nesta versão a função number_format espera que o primeiro parâmetro seja um float. Faz uma casting de tipo usando a função floatvar (http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.floatval.php). Uma outra opção é na query você forçar o campo quando nulo retornar 0. Se estiver usando o MySQL, use a função IFNULL (http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-ifnull/).

Espero ter ajudado.

**EDIT**

Em relação ao tipo recebido pela função, realmente não há problema se o valor for uma string, conforme a resposta do @Guilherme Nascimento.

Comment: alterei a versão do PHP, o erro persiste, como não foi eu que fiz o sistema, apenas migrei de hospedagem, mas tenho certeza que é na hospedagem, na outra antiga funciona normalmente.